# An inequality with $e^{ix}$

Tags: complex-analysis, exponential-function

I am to prove the following statement
$$\bigg|e^{ix} - \sum_{k=0}^m \frac{(ix)^k}{k!} \bigg| \le \frac{|x|^{m+1}}{(m+1)!},$$
where $x \in \mathbb{R}$.
I used Taylor's expansion of $e^x$. That led me to this
$$\bigg|\sum_{k=m+1}^{\infty}\frac{(ix)^k}{k!} \bigg| \le \frac{|x|^{m+1}}{(m+1)!}$$
Let's focus on the LHS
$$\bigg|\sum_{k=m+1}^{\infty}\frac{(ix)^k}{k!} \bigg|\le \sum_{k=m+1}^{\infty}\big|\frac{(ix)^k}{k!} \big| = \sum_{k=m+1}^{\infty}\frac{|ix|^k}{k!}$$
Because $|i| = 1$ we get
$$\sum_{k=m+1}^{\infty}\frac{|x|^k}{k!}$$
Let's look at the RHS. It's the first component of the sum on LHS. All the elements of the sum are positive thus the first one cannot be bigger then the sum. What have I done wrong?

Comment: see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder

Comment: @Hamed Those expressions are valid for real-valued functions whereas $e^{ix}\in \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: What do you mean by "first component of the sum on LHS"?

Comment: @UmbertoP. I mean that the the LHS = $\frac{|x|^{m+1}}{(m+1)!} + \sum_{k=m+2}^{\infty} \frac{|x|^k}{k!}$

Comment: I see. It might be clearer to say that RHS of the first inequality is the first term of the sum on the RHS of the third inequality. The short answer is that you used the triangle inequality - a very blunt instrument - at the first step. Kind of like starting the proof of $|2 - 1| = 1$ by estimating $|2 - 1| \le 2+1 = 3$. You threw away a lot of information.

Comment: @UmbertoP. Thank you! So how can I deal with my problem?

Comment: Perhaps writing $e^{ix} = \cos x + i\sin x$ and using Taylor's theorem for real functions $\cos$ and $\sin$. Those Taylor's polynomials could be chosen to recombine to $\sum_k^m(ix)^k/k!$, and one then has remainders for $\cos$ and $\sin$ separately. Maybe they would give the required remainder.

Comment: You have done nothing wrong per se. It's just that you have proved a loose inequality. What you want is $LHS \leq \frac{|x|^{m+1}}{(m+1)!} \leq \sum_{k=m+1}^\infty \frac{|x|^k}{k!}$. You have shown the outer inequality. The inner inequality can still hold, i.e. there is no inconsistency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Try Taylor's theorem with the integral form of the remainder, which works for complex valued functions: If $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb C$ is infinitely differentiable, then for $m=1,2,\dots,$

$$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{m}\frac{D^kf(0)}{k!}x^k +R_m(x),$$where $$ R_m(x)= \int_0^x\int_0^{t_1}\cdots \int_0^{t_m}D^{m+1}f(t_{m+1})\,dt_{m+1}\, dt_{m}\,\dots dt_{1}.$$

Comment: You could also write the remander term after partially integrating the iterated integrals away as $$R_m(x)=\int_0^x\frac{f^{(m+1)}(s)}{m!}(x-s)^m\,ds\,.$$ One can get this also without partial integration by considering the function $$g_x(s)=f(x)+f'(s)(x-s)+...+\frac{f^{(m)}(s)}{m!}(x-s)^m$$ where $g_x(x)=f(x)$, $g_x(0)=\sum_{k=0}^m\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}x^k$ the Taylor polynomial and $g_x'(s)=\frac{f^{(m+1)}(s)}{m!}(x-s)^m$. Now apply the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: @LutzL  The reason I wrote it like I did is because for me, it's the eaisest way to see it:$$f(x) = f(0)+\int_0^xf'(t)\,dt = f(0)+f'(0)x + \int_0^x(f'(t)-f'(0))\,dt$$ $$ = f(0)+f'(0)x + \int_0^x\int_0^tf''(s)\,ds\,dt$$ etc., and we just keep going with the FTC.

Comment: @zhw. (+1) Indeed.  That form of the remainder makes it nearly trivial to arrive at the coveted result given that $\left|\frac{d^{m+1}}{dt_{m+1}^{m+1}}e^{it_{m+1}}\right|=1$.  But the single integral form given by LutzL is even easier to use here.

Comment: @MarkViola  Hey MV, thanks. For some reason I can't remember any of the forms of Taylor with integral remainder. So I always have to rederive it. And so the formula I gave always seems the easiest to me

Comment: @zhw. You're welcome. As you, I don't make an effort to memorize things (I might recall incidentally) such as remainder formulae when I can quickly derive them from more basic principles.